# Calculating transfer function coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have derived the transfer function of a combination of spring mass system in `s` domain and it is of the form

```
G = (as*s + bs +c) / (ps + q)
```

I have the measured data which relates with displacement as input and force as output and i know the frequency and sampling rate.

How can I compute the values of the constants `a,b,c,p and q` using MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure that is your system model? The model you have derived is non-causal, which means it can't physically exist. Assuming you derive a causal model (e.g. 1/G), you can use MATLAB System Identification UI. The easiest method is to estimate a process model, you can start from there.

Comment: By the way non-causal system means; the output of the system is dependent on the future inputs. Thus making it impossible to exist in practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Think i need to dig into the System Identification toolbox. One last question regarding causality. Do you say it is non-causal because the number of zeros are more than poles? Is it never be possible to study such system.By the way I derived it from a spring damper combination. Thank you again

Comment: Yes, if the system's number of zeros is greater than its number of poles the system would be non-causal. I couldn't say it would never be possible, I have no idea what the academia is doing about that. But I can easily say that if you are modelling a system that actually exists or can exist, it should be causal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to give a complete answer (*), but it sounds like you are going to do some kind of least-squares curve fitting. `fminsearch` will work for that, but there are better choices. I tend to use `nlinfit` from the statistics toolbox, but there is also `lsqcurvefit` from the optimization toolbox and `fit` from the curve fitting toolbox.

(*) What exactly is your data? Is it displacement as a function of time, under a sinusoidal driving force of known frequency? But you must have data at more than one driving frequency, because you'll need to understand the response at more than one frequency to extract all 5 parameters of your transfer function, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right and i have data at more than 1 Frequency. These data are obtained with displacement as input and force as output in time domain. So i tried to do a tfestimate for the data but the output of this is a column vector of complex numbers. How exactly should i use this column vector to correlate with the theoretically derived Transfer Function. Maybe i still haven't understood the exact concept. It would be so nice of you to elaborate a little bit more on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I know nothing about `tfestimate`, so I'd recommend opening a new question if you have a specific question about that. But it sounds like your real question is about how to approach the problem of data analysis for this particular experiment. That really isn't on-topic for stackoverflow, so I'd recommend asking for help elsewhere (professor/ta is this is for a class, colleague if this is for work, etc.). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using `fminsearch`. For more information read the [function documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply. To use this i need to get the transfer function of the measured data in the above form, but when i used tfestimate i get a vector of complex numbers. Can you please advice me how to proceed further.    It would be really helpful.